# moving item failing on zero bytes

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Where am I going wrong with the below script...it checks for if files are of zero (0) bytes and then if they are it moves them to a folder.

It works fine outside of the IF statement but when I try it in the below it fails copying the files and displays the below error:

> Move-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is
>   null. At C:\Tools\jon\testing_scheduled.ps1:109 char:11
>   +     Move-Item <<<<  $moving "$scheduledpath\Move_empty"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

```
filter gettheheckout([string]$path = '.')
    {
        $move = Get-ChildItem $scheduledpath | Where-Object {$_.length -eq 0} | Foreach-Object {$_.fullName}
    }


$moving = gettheheckout
$check = @(Get-ChildItem $scheduledpath | Where-Object {$_.length -eq 0})

if ($check.length -eq 0)
{ 
    Write-host = "No files to move - Script Completed" -ForegroundColor Cyan    
} 
else 
{
    Move-Item $moving "$scheduledpath\Move_empty"

    Write-Host "Script Completed - Use Excel to Filter on commas - Have a nice day!" -ForegroundColor Cyan
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
filter gettheheckout([string]$path = '.')
    {
       Get-ChildItem $scheduledpath | Where-Object {$_.length -eq 0} | Foreach-Object {$_.fullName}
    }
```

and be sure `$scheduledpath` is a global scope variable and have a value.

Comment: your too good Christian! That was it...I must have put the variable in when trying something else! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @lara400 It happens :) Glad to help you.